# Порядок линковки библиотек SDL2

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks, sdl2

Не могу понять, с чем связан тот факт, что порядок линковки библиотек `SDL2` влияет на успешность сборки проекта.

Я работаю в `Windows 10 x64`, использую `Code::Blocks 17.12` и `MinGW 32`. Проблемы возникают при смене порядка библиотек в `Linker settings -> Other linker options`.

Так проект собирается:

```
-lmingw32
-lSDL2main
-lSDL2
```

А вот так - нет:

```
-lmingw32
-lSDL2
-lSDL2main
```

Причина невозможности сборки звучит примерно так:

```
\Users\slouken\release\SDL\SDL2-2.0.8-source\foo-x86\..\src\main\windows\SDL_windows_main.c|142|undefined reference to `SDL_wcslen'|
```

И таких сообщений очень много.

Почему так происходит? Какая вообще разница, в каком порядке выставлены параметры-имена библиотек?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc

Comment: Справедливо и логично, спасибо за информацию.